# Why is change directory not working when SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION is used

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe, script, ms-dos

I have an existing windows batch script (named as test1.bat) as below :

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set nop=4

for  /l %%z in (1, 1, %nop%) do (
set x=%%z
echo !x!
)

chdir /d D:\app\
```

Strangely for some reason , the `chdir` command at the end does not change the directory to `D:\app\`. It does not even throw an error and the script just completes.  But when i remove `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` then the `chdir` command works fine.

I want to know why `chdir` command is not working when i use `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` ?

Here is the complete code with output

When test1.bat is with `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`

```
C:\tmp>@test1.bat
1
2
3
4

C:\tmp>
```

When test1.bat is without `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`

```
C:\tmp>@test1.bat
!x!
!x!
!x!
!x!

D:\app>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question was already answered on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20153956/why-setlocal-interferes-with-chdir-in-windows-batch-files). The relevant part of the answer is the following:

> The only thing that is not obvious is that "localization of
> environment changes" doesn't just include environment variables, but
> also includes the current directory, and the delayed expansion and
> extensions states.

So you need to 'endlocal' before changing directory, making your script

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set nop=4

for  /l %%z in (1, 1, %nop%) do (
set x=%%z
echo !x!
)

endlocal

chdir /d D:\app\
```

Answer (score 2):

`ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` is a parameter passed to the
[SETLOCAL command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setlocal).
It's not this parameter that causes the problem, but the command itself.
(Try `setlocal` without any parameters and see that the same
thing happens.)

The `setlocal` command is described as:

> Starts localization of environment variables in a batch file. Localization continues until a matching endlocal command is encountered or the end of the batch file is reached.

In particular, this means that if you use `setlocal` in a script,
all environment variable changes are [lost at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020152/how-to-keep-the-value-of-a-variable-outside-a-windows-batch-script-which-uses) unless you
[take measures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262287/make-an-environment-variable-survive-endlocal).

One of the variables that is returned is the
[CD environment variable](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)
which holds the current directory.
This means that the current directory is returned and is no longer
`D:\APP`.
It seems like the `CD` command failed, but in fact it did work,
but was undone when the `.bat` script terminated.